# Compare-Object in powershell, how to return objects from both "sides"?

Tags: powershell

I have a problem which i'm trying to tackle with a powershell script. I have two servers in different geographic locations which contain some files. The problem is, the file structure in the two places is different, and the bandwidth between the sites is very low. Server 1 has the correct structure, and Server 2 has an incorrect structure, but many of the same files.

For example,

Server 1 has the path C:\Data\Adobe\Reader.exe
Server 2 has the path C:\Stuff\PDF Reader\Acrobat\Reader.exe

I would like to copy the files from Server 2's C:\Stuff folder, (only copy files which are identical) to a structure resembling Server 1 to C:\Data on Server 2, in order to save lots of file copies across the internet.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$oldsource = Get-ChildItem -recurse "\\server1\c$\Data"
$newsource = Get-ChildItem -recurse "\\server2\c$\Stuff"

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $newsource -DifferenceObject $oldsource -    Property Name,Length -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' } |
    foreach-object -process{
    Write-Host $_.FullName
        }
```

I haven't progress further because my command only outputs one "half" of the comparison, depending on which order -ReferenceObject and -DifferenceObject are. For example, in this example the output would be as follows:

\\server2\c$\Stuff\PDF Reader\Acrobat\Reader.exe

I require an output for both paths of the identical items:

\\server1\c$\Data\Adobe\Reader.exe

\\server2\c$\Stuff\PDF Reader\Acrobat\Reader.exe

I wish to return both the paths for server1 and server2 so I can do some string manipulation and build the equivalent paths on either side, but I can't figure out how to get both values back

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried any of the switches like -IncludeEqual?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that with Compare-Object. You can get the desired result by building a hashlist from one source and then comparing the second source to the hashlist. I've used this method before, but not for files.

```
$oldsource = Get-ChildItem -recurse "\\server1\c$\Data"
$newsource = Get-ChildItem -recurse "\\server2\c$\Stuff"

$hashlist=@{}
$oldsource | foreach-object { $hashlist.add($_.name+$_.length,$_.fullname) }
foreach ($newitem in $newsource)
{ 
    $oldmatch=$hashlist.item($newitem.name+$newitem.length) 
    if ($oldmatch)
    {
        write-host $oldmatch
        write-host $newitem.fullname
    }
}
```